"Datasource name too long" when connecting to DB with add_sql() from Great Expectations
context = gx.get_context()
conn_string = (
                "mssql+pyodbc://DRIVER={ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server};SERVER="
                + "......"
                + ";DATABASE="
                + "......"
                + ";Trusted_Connection=yes;"
            )

#print(conn_string)

conn = context.sources.add_sql(
    name="test", connection_string=conn_string
)


TestConnectionError: Attempt to connect to datasource failed with the following error message: (pyodbc.Error) ('IM010', '[IM010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]

The conn_string is taken from another project where the connection is made with SQLAlchemy.
Expectation was that the conn_string works as expected since Great Expectation uses SQLAlchemy aswell

Have you tried reading the SQLAlchemy documentation? The mssql+pyodbc:// URIs have the Driver and other connection string properties after the ? character.
